# I deleted VALORANT off my laptop will it delete off my PC?

Tags: pc, valorant

I deleted VALORANT off my laptop and my microsoft accounts are linked between my laptop and PC. Will it delete off both devices?

Answer (score 3):

**No,**

Physically installed programs will not delete off another computer signed into the same Microsoft account. The same as installing it on one will not install it on the other.